# JPA Hibernate Parent / Child Mapping Confusion

Tags: hibernate, jpa, mapping

Hoping someone can help me with this one.

I'm trying to create a bi-directional join between two entities using JPA / Hibernate.

I've got this problem, that seems to point to the fact, that my database column names need to match my Value Object attribute names - but this just seems weird.  Hoping someone can help me, by providing some clarity.

Unfortunately I'm in a position where some bright spark has named the column names with meaningless names.  **I am not in a position to change the column names - believe me - if I could - I would!**

So here's what my schema looks like:-

```
Customer
========
CS1 -- The ID column
CS2 -- Customer Description

ContactDetails
==============
CD1 -- The ID column
CD2 -- The FK to the Customer table
...
```

As you'd expect I have two Value Objects, within my application - these look like this:-

**Customer.java**

```
@Entity
@Table("Customer")
public class Customer {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "CS1", nullable=false, columnDefinition="INTEGER")
  private int id;
}

@OneToMany  (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "customerId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
private Set <ContactDetailsVO> contactDetails = new HashSet <CustomerDetailsVO> ();
}
```

**ContactDetails.java**

```
public class ContactDetails {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "CD1", nullable=false, columnDefinition="INTEGER")
  private int id;

@Column(name = "CD2")
long customerId;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "customerId", referencedColumnName = "id")
private CustomerVO customer;

public CustomerVO getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

public void setCustomer(CustomerVO customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}
}
```

Unfortunately, this approach of referencing the Object attribute names, for the mapping relationships doesn't seem to work - and I get the following, at startup:-

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: customerId in TestDB.dbo.ContactDetails
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:131
```

So if I then change the mappings to make use of the actual table column names instead, I get the following:-

**Customer.java**

```
@Entity
@Table("Customer")
public class Customer {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "CS1", nullable=false, columnDefinition="INTEGER")
  private int id;
}

@OneToMany  (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "CD2", fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
private Set <ContactDetailsVO> contactDetails = new HashSet <CustomerDetailsVO> ();
}
```

**ContactDetails.java**

```
public class ContactDetails {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "CD1", nullable=false, columnDefinition="INTEGER")
  private int id;

@Column(name = "CD2")
long customerId;

@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "CD2", referencedColumnName = "CS1")
private CustomerVO customer;

public CustomerVO getCustomer() {
    return customer;
}

public void setCustomer(CustomerVO customer) {
    this.customer = customer;
}
}
```

Then I get the following:-

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: 
com.myCompany.model.vo.CustomerVO, at table: ContactDetails, for columns: 
      [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(customer)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:306)
```

As I say, the obvious way to solve this is to name my object attributes, the same as the table column names - but given the stupidity that went into naming the table columns, I'd rather isolate my application from it.

Can someone please help shed some light on this strange behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Ok - so this is a real problem in Hibernate I think.  Basically if you mix attribute and method annotation decoration methods, Hibernate gives you bogus, meaningless errors.  Hope this saves someone the 6 hours I just wasted on it.